# php variable not found with vtiger code

Tags: php, vtiger

I am installing vtiger in my mac os.

i am getting this error when accessing `index.php`

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vtigercrm/modules/CustomView/CustomView.php on line 17
```

So the error clearly says that there is a variable `mod_strings` that is not identified.

I went to `index.php` and I found this:

```
include_once 'include/Webservices/Relation.php';
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';
include_once 'includes/main/WebUI.php';

$webUI = new Vtiger_WebUI();
$webUI->process(new Vtiger_Request($_REQUEST, $_REQUEST));
```

As you see, the error tells me that the variable is in the `CustomView.php`. So I opened that file, and I found the followings:

```
require_once('data/CRMEntity.php');
require_once('include/utils/utils.php');
require_once 'include/Webservices/Utils.php';
```

as you see, the code is using a php script called `CRMEntity`, i opened that file and I found this:

```
global $adb, $mod_strings;
```

so look the variable **IS** there. why i am getting that error?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have installed?

Comment: @RalphMelhem i have xampp 5.6.12-0 i don't know with which version it comes.

Comment: run phpinfo(); and let me know which version of php it shows, it might be a compatibility issue here

Comment: @RalphMelhem i got `PHP Version 5.6.12`

Comment: Which Browser are you testing on? Kindly note Safari is not supported

Comment: @RalphMelhem it is google chrome not safari

Answer (score 0):

Based on the system requirements [here](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/System_Requirements), you should configure your php.ini to the following:

error_reporting     E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors  on

Check in phpinfo() the location of the php.ini being used and apply the changes to it, then restart your server and test

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, I'm trying to install vTiger and I'm stuck with the same error and you gave me good hints, like you said, `$mod_strings` is declared `global` in `CRMEntity.php` sp in order to fix this problem, just add it to the global declaration in `CustomView.php` like so :

```
require_once 'data/CRMEntity.php';
require_once 'include/utils/utils.php';
require_once 'include/Webservices/Utils.php';
// add $mod_strings
global $adv_filter_options, $mod_strings;
// the rest of the code ...
$adv_filter_options = array("e" => "" . $mod_strings['equals'] . "",
// ...
```

You may also need to hide the errors in order to see the install page (you can't correct all of the errors, there are just many that you may wish you developed your own CRM)

in `"vtigercrm\include\logging.php"` at the top add the following

```
// hide errors
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
// but log them
error_reporting(e_all | e_strict);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `error_reporting('e_all' | 'e_strict');` instead?